# how to loop though div and get each value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get each value within my div. I am using

```
var cart = $('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').text();
```

It is giving the results of `OI-01OP-01OS-10-5SOR-04OR-05`
I need to view them one by one: `OI-01, OP-01, OS-10-5S, OR-04 OR-05`.

So that I can match them against another field.
If you care to help me further, I have another div on the page:

```
var ParNum = $('.assess-title').text();
```

I would like to compare the values returned from the `var cart` and see if that value is in the `ParNum`. If it is there, I would like to apply a class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to iterate over elements:

```
var text = '';
$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').each(function (i, div) {
  text += ' ' + $(div).text();
});
```

or this to get an array of matching div elements:

```
var divs = $('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').toArray();
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  // $(div).text();
}
```

Reason for this is that `$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell')` returns all div's at once, and you need to loop through the result. More specifically, `$(selector)` returns a so-called "wrapped set". It can be used to access each matching element (as I've shown above) or it can be used to apply any other jQuery function to the whole set at once. More info [here](http://www.vfstech.com/?p=40).

Answer (score 3):

You can store the values in an array using `.map()` method:

```
var values = $('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').map(function() {
    return $.trim( $(this).text() );
}).get();
```

For checking existence of the `ParNum` value in the array:

```
var does_exist = values.indexOf(ParNum) > -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "";

$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').each(function(){ 
   text += $(this).text() + ", ";
});
// remove the last ", " from string
text = text.substr(0, text.length -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cart = [];
$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').each(function {
    cart.push($(this).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This performs the matching and class adding you mentioned in the question.

```
var ParNum = $('.assess-title').text();
$('basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == ParNum) {
        $(this).addClass("someclass");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

```
var cart ='';
$('.basic-cart-cart-node-title'.find('.cell').each(function()
{
 cart = cart + $(this).val();
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
var cart = $('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').text().match(/.{5}/g);
```

This will give you an array with items 5 chars long. Regexes arent very fast, but a loop might be slower

Or easier to read, and in a string with commas:

```
var cart = $('.basic-cart-cart-node-title.cell').text(); // get text
cart = cart.match(/.{1,5}/g); // split into 5 char long pieces
cart = cart.join(",",); join on comma
```

Comment: And if any of the cells have contents that aren't 5 characters long? JS and jQuery have perfectly good iteration constructs, this seems like a particularly backward way to do it.

Comment: This answer is related to the topic. Keeping in mind it might change, sure, but the answer is perfectly fine related to the question.